# Using DateDiff to work as Excel Networkdays

Tags: sql, datediff

Happy New Year to all.

So I am trying to work out the difference between today's date `(GETDATE())` and a Target Date in a specific table `(targetdate)`

When I use the DATEDIFF function it is including non working days in the calculation (weekends and bank holidays). Although our date calandar table provided to us from a third party supplier will tell you the weekends, it does not tell you the bank holidays.

Luckily there is another table in the database called - ih_non_work_days.

The format of the date is `"2014-12-25 00:00:00.000"` for example in that table.

How do I using my `"targetdate" and today's date` calculate in days the differance - excluding the dates that exist in the `ih_non_work_days` database?

So for now my basic script looks like -

```
SELECT   com.comm_reference AS 'Referance'
     ,com.current_task_target_date AS 'TargetDate'
             , DATEDIFF(D,com.current_task_target_date,GETDATE()) AS 'Incorrect Date Calculation'
FROM [dbo].[em_communication] as com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.comm_reference AS Referance ,C.current_task_target_date AS TargetDate ,DATEDIFF(d, C.current_task_target_date,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - NoWorkDays AS 'Days Past Target Date' FROM [dbo].[em_communication] C CROSS APPLY ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoWorkDays FROM [dbo].[ih_non_work_days] D WHERE D.date_off BETWEEN C.current_task_target_date AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) N;
```